# how can I connect to the display on a google cloud machine?

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform

I have succesfully created a machine on Google Cloud which I can access via

```
gcloud compute ssh my-service
```

however passing -X to ssh is not an option and I would like to see some plots.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean with:

> however passing -X to ssh is not an option and I would like to see some plots.

But you can also use the google console to connect to the SSH and get system usage graphs like CPU, Memory, Disk and Network usage.

Answer (score 0):

Linux instances on GCP are server versions of the OS. There is no desktop. You can try using a VNC viewer like [TigerVNC](http://tigervnc.org/) to get a similar desktop interface. You can also [RDP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#windows) to a windows instance to get a windows desktop. Your question is unclear. You will need to be more specific as to what you mean by "plots", "connect to the display", "-X" these terms are all very general and specific to your personal environment wherever you were.